# MVC 5 - jQueryUI Dialog View not displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-ui-dialog

I am working on a MVC website and for my delete function I decided to use jQuery UI Dialog to display a popup style dialog box for the user to confirm that they wish to delete the object. My problem is that it is not displaying as intended, when I select to delete I can see my partial view dialog popup for a split second before I am redirected to another page that displays my confirmation message and the button to delete.

This is my delete controller:

```
//Deletes a selected club
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DeletePartialView(int? id) //Original: public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Club club = db.Clubs.Find(id);
        if (club == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return PartialView(club);
    }
    [HttpPost, ActionName("DeletePartialView")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id) //Original: public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Club club = db.Clubs.Find(id);
        var MembersToDelete = club.ClubMembers.ToList();
        foreach (var item in MembersToDelete)
        {
            db.ClubMembers.Remove(item);
        }

        db.Clubs.Remove(club);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

This is the Delete button and the partial view in its div:

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ClubID }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-xs" }) |
                            @*@Html.ActionLink("Delete Partial", "DeletePartialView", new { id = item.ClubID }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-xs" })*@

                            @Html.ActionLink(
                            "Delete Partial",
                            "DeletePartialView",
                            new { id = item.ClubID },
                            new
                            {
                            @class = "btn btn-danger btn-xs",
                            id = "deleteClub-opener" //Button ID
                                                           })

   @* Delete Club Popup*@
    <div id="DelteClub-dialog" title="Delete Club">
        @Html.Partial("DeletePartialView", new ultimateorganiser.Models.Club())
    </div>
```

This is the jQuery code:

```
//Delete Club Dialog Window with effects
        $(function () {
            $("#DelteClub-dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 500,
                width: 600,
                show: {
                    effect: "clip",
                    duration: 500
                },
                hide: {
                    effect: "highlight",
                    duration: 1000
                }
            });

            //Open Delete Club Dialog Window
            $("#deleteClub-opener").click(function () {
                $("#DelteClub-dialog").dialog("open");
            });
        })
```

;

This is how it is currently displaying:
[image]

This is what my DeletePartialView looks like:

```
@model ultimateorganiser.Models.Club
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}
<h3 class="text-warning">Are you sure you want to delete this club?</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" />
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
}
```

Comment: You need to cancel the default redirect. add `return false;` after `$("#DelteClub-dialog").dialog("open");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preventDefault` in the `jQuery` binding.

```
$("#deleteClub-opener").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#DelteClub-dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

Alternatively, you can also `return false` in the binding function to prevent event propagation.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work and for some reason when I add that line I can no longer see my popup flash instead it seems to jump straight into the page

Comment: yes that allows the dialog box to display but now the delete action no longer works

Comment: @CathalO'Donnell, Your dialog needs a button to post the value to you controller method. It a bit unclear what your actually wanting to do because you have not shown the relevant code (whats in your dialog?)

Comment: I have updated my question to include my Partial View

Answer (score 0):

So far your are good now. To make the delete work add following in your Delete partial view after begin form

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="@Model.Id"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  please check this code.and tell me another problem for using the dialog box.
only use this library
<html>
<head>
<link href="~/library/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/library/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/library/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <div>    
     <button id="btnCreate" class="btn-btn-primary">open the dialog</button> 
    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(function () {
                    $.noConflict(true);
                    $("#dialog").dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        draggable: true,
                        resizable: true,
                        dialogClass: "alert",
                        modal: true
                    });

                    $("#btnCreate").click(function () {
                        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                    });
                });
            });

    <body>
     <div id="dialog" style ="display:none" class="form" title="Basic dialog">
      <table>
           <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <td><input type ="text" id="txtName" style= "width:200px" />
          </tr>
           <tr>
              <th>Age</th>
              <td><input type ="text" id="txtAge"  style= "width:200px" />
          </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><input type="submit" value="Create" id="btnCreateId" class="btn btn-Sucess"  />
              <td><input type="button" value="Cancel" id="txtCancel" class="btn btn-danger"/>
          </tr> 
      </table>
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```